# How to select the second derivative greater than 1 in r

Tags: r, derivative, dbscan

I'm looking for the exact value of epsilon to run the `DBSCAN` clustering algorithm.

Here's the `KNN` distance plot.

[image: KNN distplot]

This chart has two flex points. I need the second flex point. I'm using the following code:

```
# evaluate kNN distance
dist <- dbscan::kNNdist(iris, 4)

# order result
dist <- dist[order(dist)]

# scale
dist <- dist / max(dist)

# derivative
ddist <- diff(dist) / ( 1 / length(dist))

# get first point where derivative is higher than 1
knee <- dist[length(ddist)- length(ddist[ddist > 1])]
```

How can improve my code to get second point where derivative is higher than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't reproduce your code (perhaps because of package version conflict), but it seems that `which` function would help you to find all positions, where `ddist > 1`: `which(ddist > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Because the x and y axes are *not* comparable, this approach doesn't work. It's too sensitive to scale.

Finding the elbow/knee/inflexion is subjective and cannot reliably be automated.